# Relation between CPUs and vCPUs in GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Would like to know whether 1vCPU in GCE VM is equal to 1CPU.
On prem server has got 8CPUs and want to find equivalent server in GCE VM.
Should I opt for 8vCPUs or 16vCPUs?

Would be thankful if any Google documentation reference is provided.

Comment: You state "8CPUs". Is this 8 physical CPUs or one CPU with 8 cores? Very different systems with very different architectures. In the real world we do not care what size a vCPU is in relation to a physical CPU. When performance is a factor, benchmark. The performance of a CPU, vCPU, etc depends on the processor and support chips and backplane and etc. and there are a vast number of different types with very different performance numbers. Usually the important numbers are RAM and disk IOPS with CPU coming in last.

Answer (score 0):

As per this GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms) a vCPU is a single hardware hyper-thread on one of the CPU processors. For example, Intel Xeon processors [Hyper-threading technology](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hyper-threading/hyper-threading-technology.html) support multiple threads in a single physical core. You can configure an instance with one or more of these hyper-threads as vCPUs.

A physical CPU is actual hardware unit installed in motherboard socket. To calculate vCPU that is equivalent 8CPU to you can follow this [doc](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-CPU-and-VCPU).